# Why when saving my matplotlib image, the title does not appear?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have made a plot. I have set my own legend. When I save the image, the title does not appear. I do not know why.

Here is my code:

```
ax = plt.gca()
df1_MAXN.plot(kind = 'line', y = 'MemUsed', ax=ax, legend=True, label='MAXN')
df1_MAXQ.plot(kind = 'line', y = 'MemUsed', color='red', ax=ax, legend=True, label='MAXQ')


#Annotate the max values using the data coordenates
ax.annotate('3284.97',xy=(70000, 3284.97), xycoords='data')
ax.annotate('2903.8',xy=(70000, 2903.8), xycoords='data')

#Remove top and right axis
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

#The legend
myLegend=plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.1, 1., .102), prop ={'size':10}, loc='center',frameon=False, ncol=2, title=r'TX2 (GPU) USED MEMORY - I_V1')                    
myLegend.get_title().set_fontsize('14')


ax.set_xlabel("NUMBER OF INFERENCES")
ax.set_ylabel("USED MEMORY (MB)")
plt.savefig('Memory_Iv1_TX2.png', dpi = 1000)
plt.show()
```

This is how the saved image looks like:
[image]

This is how it should be:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have just found the answer. I added `bbox_inches='tight`. And now the title appears in the saved image :)

```
#Save image removing the whitespace around it
plt.savefig('Memory_Iv1_TX2.png', bbox_inches='tight', dpi = 1000)
plt.show()
```